# Html email template compatible to mobiles

Tags: html, css, media-queries, newsletter

i am coding html email that should be `valid for  mobiles and monitors`  ,  i know   how to  code email template and i have coded it perfectly for monitors  now problems comes with `mobile compatibility` .. see attached image  `left one for monitors` is perfect but for mobiles its all broken ,  i did see `media queries` but really not getting how to use them , can someone help me with it

> if i have a **td** and when viewed on computers its **two column layout** 
>   **but for mobiles it should show one coluomn in a row** as in image and
>   also how to adjust one image to full screen ..as i want yellow images to be in full screen and heading right under in full screen width

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you inserted the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1.0"/>
```

After that you can insert media queries in your CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ...
}
```

You can find more information about responsive html emails here: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/06/responsive-html-email-design/

Comment: should i set "width=device-width" to mobile width ?

Comment: use the tag as in my example for more flexible layout or content="width=320" for mobile design is purposely laid out at 320px